# Why is UV mapped texture not visible on workbench in B.2.8?

Tags: texturing, opengl, workbench-render-engine

I made a simple factory building with two materials.

- One material [factory_floor_material] is assigned to the floor of the factory.
- One material [factory_wall_material] is assigned to the walls of the factory.

Each material has a texture, and each texture is UV mapped to the appropriate parts of the model.

If I switch to EEVEE or Cycles, everything looks fine, however if I switch to Workbench, I see the floor texture is visible, but the texture of the walls are not there.

I believe this is because the walls have been edited a little bit in *Edit Mode* (i.e. loop cuts added, faces deleted).

Does anybody have any idea how to fix that?

Workbench view: Clearly, the walls' texture is not visible, however the floor's texture is.

[image: screenshot of the workbench view. clearly, the walls' texture is not visible, however the floor's texture is.]

[image]

Comment: "*.blend file here expires on February 30 2020*" Use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to share your files here

Comment: Do you see the material on the outside of the walls?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @DuarteFarrajotaRamos!

Comment: @mick No I don't see any textures outside of the walls. I thought it might have been a problem with the normals, but apparently it is not.